# PlotLegends and ColorConvert interact badly

Tags: color, legending

I want to make a plot, then check how it looks in GrayScale. If I use PlotLegends->Automatic, this isn't an issue:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
ColorConvert[%, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]
[image]

But if I try to specify PlotLegends then ColorConvert throws an error:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"myplot"}]
ColorConvert[%, "Grayscale"]

>> [Appropriate first plot]
>> Rule::argr: Rule called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.
```

In my use case, PlotLegends -> Automatic isn't possible (without tons of extra work), so this is a problem.

What's going on?

Comment: what happens if you try something like `plot /. x_RGBColor:>ColorConvert[x,"Grayscale"]`

Comment: That does the trick! Can you write an answer explaining what you did there? (I'm not familiar with the syntax)

Comment: I get an additional error that says 'ColorConvert:[your plot is shown] should be a valid image, a color directive, a list of machine-sized real numbers of length up to 5, or a list of such objects.` If you apply `FullForm` to your plots: with automatic legend you get a graphics object, and the explicitly legended plot is wrapped in the head `Legended`. My guess is `ColorConvert` doesn't recognize `Legended` as a valid image. Mike is using the replacement rule to apply `ColorConvert` to RGB tuples directly, which ignores the `Legended` head.

Answer (score 4):

For example

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"myplot"}] /. x_RGBColor:>ColorConvert[x,"Grayscale"]
```

which looks for heads with `RGBColor` and applies the colour conversion. Colours can also be `GrayScale` and `Hue` so more generally search for all colours (@kglr)

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"myplot"}] /. x_?ColorQ:>ColorConvert[x,"Grayscale"]
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what that syntax is doing that's different from what I tried?

Comment: (+1) more generally,  `x_?ColorQ` instead of `x_RGBColor`.